# How to iterate array value in javascript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

while clicking the button i want to check the array field value is null or not

code

```
function renderblock(){
         alert('jjj');
         var result = '{!filterArray}';
           alert(result );
  }
```

Alert result ::filterArray values :

> [filterField:[label=AccountName, searchFieldName=FULL_NAME,
>   searchValue=]],  [filterField:[label=City, searchFieldName=PRIM_CITY,
>   searchValue=test]],  [filterField:[label=Country,
>   searchFieldName=PRIM_COUNTRY_NM, searchValue=]], 
>   [filterField:[label=Street Address, searchFieldName=PRIM_ADDR_LN_1,
>   searchValue=]],  [filterField:[label=State/Province,
>   searchFieldName=PRIM_STATE, searchValue=]], 
>   [filterField:[label=Zip/PostalCode, searchFieldName=PRIM_POSTAL_CD,
>   searchValue=]]

In the controller my array value is :

> [filterField:[label=AccountName, searchFieldName=FULL_NAME,
>   searchValue=]],  [filterField:[label=City, searchFieldName=PRIM_CITY,
>   searchValue=test]],  [filterField:[label=Country,
>   searchFieldName=PRIM_COUNTRY_NM, searchValue=]], 
>   [filterField:[label=Street Address, searchFieldName=PRIM_ADDR_LN_1,
>   searchValue=]],  [filterField:[label=State/Province,
>   searchFieldName=PRIM_STATE, searchValue=test]], 
>   [filterField:[label=Zip/PostalCode, searchFieldName=PRIM_POSTAL_CD,
>   searchValue=uma]]

Means am having value for "serachfield" But when i click the button javascript is called first and giving empty values.how to overcome this ?

In this array i want to check atleast one searchvalue attribute is filled or not ..Please help

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using JSON serialize string in apex

```
public String getJsonArray()
{
  return JSON.serialize(filterArray);
}
```

and again in VF page use

```
<script>

    var arraylist = JSON.parse('{!JsonArray}');
    for(var i = 0; i<arraylist.length; i++)
    {
      console.log(arraylist[i]); //check here field null or not
    }

</script>
```

Comment: could you please review my question again.I just edited now

Comment: when you click on button and call the apex method. you have rerender in VF page to get the updated values @ramu